# How to convert ECDSA SIG signature to array of characters in C

Tags: c, sockets, openssl, sign, ecdsa

I'm a beginner to cryptography (openssl library) and I wanted help on how to send an ECDSA signature through a C socket communication. My plan is:

1. make socket connection
2. convert ECDSA SIG object into string
3. send signature in the form of a string
4. At the destination, convert the string back to SIG object and verify signing

Here is the code.

```
static ECDSA_SIG* sig = NULL;
static EC_KEY    *eckey = NULL;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{         
    unsigned char* msgDigest = "6df19ccf6b89397c9a9906bfd0848f061352e9b5";
    if(ECDSAsign()) 
        printf("signed successfully\n");
    else
        printf("signing failed\n"); 

    ...
}

int ECDSAsign()
{
    int ret;

    eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp192k1);
    if (eckey == NULL)
    {
        printf(" error ");
        return 0;
    }

    if (!EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey))
    {
        printf(" error ");
        return 0;
    }

     unsigned char *buffer, *pp;
     int bufLen;
     bufLen = ECDSA_size(eckey);
     buffer = OPENSSL_malloc(bufLen);
     pp = buffer;
     unsigned char *dgst = "5df19ccf6b89397c9a9906bfd0848f061352e9ba";
     sig = ECDSA_do_sign(dgst, strlen(dgst), eckey);
     if (sig == NULL)
     {
        printf(" Signature NOT generated\n ");
        return 0;
     }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert ECDSA SIG signature to array of characters in C
>   ...

The signature is already an array of bytes. That is what is returned from `EVP_DigestSignFinal`.

---

In general, you want to use the `EVP_*` interfaces for signing and verification. Below is from the OpenSSL wiki on [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying).

Your job below is to get the ECDSA into the `EVP_PKEY*`. The function will allocate the signature buffer with `OPENSSL_malloc`. The caller needs to free it with `OPENSSL_free`. The buffer is an array of bytes.

```
int sign_it(const byte* msg, size_t mlen, byte** sig, size_t* slen, EVP_PKEY* pkey)
{
    /* Returned to caller */
    int result = -1;

    if(!msg || !mlen || !sig || !pkey) {
        assert(0);
        return -1;
    }

    if(*sig)
        OPENSSL_free(*sig);

    *sig = NULL;
    *slen = 0;

    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = NULL;

    do
    {
        ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
        assert(ctx != NULL);
        if(ctx == NULL) {
            printf("EVP_MD_CTX_create failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        const EVP_MD* md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256");
        assert(md != NULL);
        if(md == NULL) {
            printf("EVP_get_digestbyname failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        int rc = EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, md, NULL);
        assert(rc == 1);
        if(rc != 1) {
            printf("EVP_DigestInit_ex failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        rc = EVP_DigestSignInit(ctx, NULL, md, NULL, pkey);
        assert(rc == 1);
        if(rc != 1) {
            printf("EVP_DigestSignInit failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        rc = EVP_DigestSignUpdate(ctx, msg, mlen);
        assert(rc == 1);
        if(rc != 1) {
            printf("EVP_DigestSignUpdate failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        size_t req = 0;
        rc = EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, NULL, &req);
        assert(rc == 1);
        if(rc != 1) {
            printf("EVP_DigestSignFinal failed (1), error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        assert(req > 0);
        if(!(req > 0)) {
            printf("EVP_DigestSignFinal failed (2), error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        *sig = OPENSSL_malloc(req);
        assert(*sig != NULL);
        if(*sig == NULL) {
            printf("OPENSSL_malloc failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        *slen = req;
        rc = EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, *sig, slen);
        assert(rc == 1);
        if(rc != 1) {
            printf("EVP_DigestSignFinal failed (3), return code %d, error 0x%lx\n", rc, ERR_get_error());
            break; /* failed */
        }

        assert(req == *slen);
        if(rc != 1) {
            printf("EVP_DigestSignFinal failed, mismatched signature sizes %ld, %ld", req, *slen);
            break; /* failed */
        }

        result = 0;

    } while(0);

    if(ctx) {
        EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(ctx);
        ctx = NULL;
    }

    /* Convert to 0/1 result */
    return !!result;
}
```